# The url field missing in spreadsheet while exporting csv of products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to export a CSV file with woocommerce products, however after exporting the URL of the product in column is missing. I've tried also to export one product on a fresh Woocommerce install, but the problem still occurs even with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the official method doesn't work for me right now. There is an alternative solution using `WP All Export` plugin